# How to generate SSL certificate using openSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I've a server app that uses non-secure connection with clients and I would like to add SSL certificate to my server. I've installed OpenSSL version 1.0.1e Version on Windows 7. And my first question is how to create SSL certificate? And if possible can I make random keys for so that my server could change keys every specific time?

Comment: Your first question should be "is the idea worth it". Unless you are building a solution in specific closed environment (i.e. for intranet web site) it's a better idea to purchase the certificate from well-known certificate authority. This will save you from making every client trust your self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good but requires a lot of work. The earlier suggestion is correct. It would be best to just purchase an SSL certificate from top CAs.

There are a lot of cheap but secure certificates you can get depending on your needs, you just need to generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) from your web server (In your case - OpenSSL). Now a days, some CAs also offers an Auto-CSR where they will be creating the CSR for you. You may also check it here: https://www.globalsign.com/support/csr/autocsr_domain_organization.php